# How to split a sentence in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I need to isolate every single word of a long, natural text in Python3.

What is the more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Writing some Python code is an excellent way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your text is already split into sentences, just use

```
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
```

(see [tokenization](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) from [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)).

If you need to split by sentences first, take a look at [this part](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.punkt) (there is code sample).